# What is the difference between "über" and "auf"?

Tags: difference, preposition

According to the dictionary, both *über* and *auf* mean *above.* So what is the difference between the two?

Comment: You want to re-check. The main translation of *auf* is **not** *above*.

Comment: "Above" is "über" - "auf" is "on", "onto", "upon"...

Comment: What @tofro said ... More specifically:  http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/auf_Praeposition  vs http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/ueber_auf_darueber_darauf

Comment: *Über* means *over* or *above*. *Auf* means *on* or derivates: *upon*, *onto*.

Answer (score 4):

Referring *»above«* as *»oberhalb«* **auf** ist used if things have contact, **über** is used if things have either contact or a vertical distance from each other.

Contact:

> Ein Buch liegt **auf** dem anderen.
>
> Ein Buch liegt **über** dem anderen.

Distance:

> Das Flugzeug fliegt **über** den Wolken.
>
> Das dritte Stockwerk liegt **über** dem ersten.

Answer (score 1):

Auf und über haben auch ja andere Bedeutungen, wenn es natürlich nicht um Kontakt oder Ort geht.

> Das bezieht sich auf...

It refers to...

> Achten Sie auf...

Pay attention to...

> Er spricht über...

He speaks about...

Comment: Welcome @Ali. Good point I find. I have allowed myself to comb it a bit to give it a 'viewing experience' similar to the other answer.

Answer (score 0):

*Auf* refers to *over* in the sense of *on*, eg: "Das Buch liegt auf den Tisch" = "The book is on the table", **not** "The book is over the table."